# Tablesorter pager not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, tablesorter

I am developing android app using Jquery Mobile.
I am having some problem with tablesorter plugin with pager.

Here is my HTML page

```
    <div id="mainPager" class="pager">
    <form>

    <div class="ui-grid-d">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="&lt;&lt;" class="first" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="&lt;" class="prev" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="text" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" class="pagedisplay"/></div>
        <div class="ui-block-d"><input type="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="&gt;" class="next" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-e"><input type="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="&gt;&gt;" class="last" /></div>
    </div>
    <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>

            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>


<table class="myTable" id="dataTable" >
  <thead>

    </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>

</table>
```

This is my jquery code.

```
  $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#main' ,function(){       

    fillRoTable() ;    

    });



  function fillRoTable() 
  { 

   var html = '';
     for (var key=0, size= 1; key<size;key++) {
      html += '<tr><th>'
         + "Ticket #"
         + '</th><th>'
         + "Action"
         + '</th></tr>';
      }

    $('#dataTable thead').append(html);


    $.ajax({url: "h**p://xyz.com/test/info?client=ig&docId=2313",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: true,
    success: function (result) { 

var html1 = '';
for (var key=0, size=25; key<size; key++) {

html1 += '<tr><td>'
         + key
         + '</td><td>'
         + (size-key)
         + '</td></tr>';
}

$('#dataTable tbody').append(html1);


              $("#dataTable").tablesorter()
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#MainPager"), positionFixed: false});    



    },
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
    }
 });   

}
```

Now my problem is that when main page loads everything is looking fine but if I tap on one of the heading to sort the column then I table becomes empty.

Can anyone suggest me what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we [solved this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/416) by updating the pager script from the original plugin (v2.0.5) to the one from my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).